# Define bbox for WMS service

Tags: geoserver, wms, wps, bbox

There is such a task: you need to display one of the raster layer and  one or several vector objects (use layer CQL of filter).

I use geoserver to store the geodata and leaflet js on the client to display geodata.

One "beautiful" solutions is to use WMS with several layers and filters for vector layer.

For it i must define bbox. How can i do it?

I have input data:

- size of the picture
- bounding box of geoobjects

I need result: bbox

[For examples](https://nowcoast.noaa.gov/arcgis/services/nowcoast/analysis_meteohydro_sfc_qpe_time/MapServer/WmsServer?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=5&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=true&version=1.1.1&height=256&width=256&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=-15028131.257091932,2504688.542848655,-12523442.714243276,5009377.085697314)

Comment: may need more explanations?

Comment: The example you give has an error, the layer name provided is incorrect, and I'm not sure what it is intended to show.  Also the service shown in the example is not provided by GeoServer it's ArcGIS, so  how does this service relate to your question?

Comment: Here is a working GetMap request for the service you give as an example:   https://nowcoast.noaa.gov/arcgis/services/nowcoast/analysis_meteohydro_sfc_qpe_time/MapServer/WmsServer?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=-14471533.8030999992,2273278.607600000221,-6678646.402836999856,7361866.30700000003&CRS=EPSG:3857&WIDTH=800&HEIGHT=523&LAYERS=5&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/jpeg&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:96&